# Efficient way to resample the duration of events to regular intervals in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

#### Problem description

I have a dataframe detailing the start and end times of some events. **We can assume events do not overlap, but it'd be better if we don't**. For example:

```
events = pd.DataFrame([["2018-03-01 09:10:00", "2018-03-01 10:15:00"],
                       ["2018-03-01 12:40:00", "2018-03-01 14:05:00"],
                       ["2018-03-01 14:30:00", "2018-03-01 14:45:00"]],
                      columns=["starttime", "endtime"])
events = events.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

I want to resample these data into regular intervals. For each interval, then, I want to know during how much time there was at least one active event. For example, if resampling the previous events into 1-hour intervals, I would expect the following results:

```
                start                 end event_time
0 2018-03-01 08:00:00 2018-03-01 09:00:00   00:00:00
1 2018-03-01 09:00:00 2018-03-01 10:00:00   00:50:00
2 2018-03-01 10:00:00 2018-03-01 11:00:00   00:15:00
3 2018-03-01 11:00:00 2018-03-01 12:00:00   00:00:00
4 2018-03-01 12:00:00 2018-03-01 13:00:00   00:20:00
5 2018-03-01 13:00:00 2018-03-01 14:00:00   01:00:00
6 2018-03-01 14:00:00 2018-03-01 15:00:00   00:20:00
7 2018-03-01 15:00:00 2018-03-01 16:00:00   00:00:00
```

Notice that between 14:00 and 15:00, two events occur at different times, so the total time that at least one event was active is 20 min (5 min + 15 min).

#### Attempted solution

The only way I found to do this transformation involves `DataFrame.iterrows()`. For the record, this solution assumes the events do not overlap.

```
start = pd.date_range("2018-03-01 08:00", "2018-03-01 15:59", freq="1H")
end = start.shift(1)
data = pd.DataFrame({"start": start, "end": end})
data = data.reindex(columns=["start", "end"])

data = data.assign(event_time=pd.Timedelta("0s"))
for idx, row in events.iterrows():
    overlap = ((data.start < row.endtime) & (data.end > row.starttime))
    overlap_start = data[overlap].start.clip(lower=row.starttime)
    overlap_end = data[overlap].end.clip(upper=row.endtime)
    data.loc[overlap, "event_time"] += overlap_end - overlap_start
```

The main problem with this solution is that it's rather inefficient when both dataframes grow (events and resampled one). Specifically, for an `events` dataframe with 81000 records and a `data` dataframe with 30000, it takes more than 20 minutes.

#### Question

Is there any better way to get the results? I'm specially interested in efficiency with larger dataframes.